# How to use HTTP/2 with ArcGIS Online for img tiles?

Tags: http, arcgis, http2, arcgis-js-api

If you work with ArcGIS Online the needed JS Code is downloaded from `js.arcgis.com` via HTTP/2. But all the image tiles coming from the domains `services.arcgisonline.com` and `server.arcgisonline.com` still use the old HTTP/1 protocol.
Am I missing something here? Why would they not have HTTP/2 for all the image tiles.

Comment: Since the server doesn't support http2 there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @emix How could they not support HTTP/2 for all the img tiles delivery. Wouldn't that be no. 1 priority?

Comment: I guess this is the question to the site admin, not us.